# socket io react native probleme (this.mapData is not a function)

Tags: react-native, socket.io

i have a probleme with socket io with react native.. iget error this.mapData is not a function i searched i didnt find a solution could anyone help me with this
and thank you

Comment: please provide code where you had this issue, it is hard to understand what is wrong here without it.

Comment: const io = require('socket.io-client/socket.io')                                                                                          
this.socket =  io('http://192.168.1.10:3000')    this.socket.emit('RESERVE_MISSSION')                                                                                                                                                                                                          
 the error is : this.mapData is not a function

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your require statement value incorrect. Try like this

`const io = require('socket.io-client');`

I checked it with Expo snack and it doesn't produce any errors. Have a look https://snack.expo.io/@troublediehard/aG9uZX

Comment: same error : undefined is not a function (evaluating 'this.mapdata()')

Comment: @AlaaMokrani did you check my snack? it is not reproduced here. Probably something specific for your environment setup.

Comment: yes i did ..and i did exactly the same but it keep giving me the same error

Comment: the only way I can try to help you if you can create a sample project (for example on the github) with this issue so I can get and reproduce it on my side.